# "Media" folder not being created with Django's FileSystemStorage. Files don't get saved if made manually either

Tags: python, django, ajax, pycharm, file-system-storage

So, I always test out new things in a separate project and the example that I used to test this out worked. However, trying to integrate the same in my project doesn't give me the results I need. I've spent close to 4 hours on this now and nothing so far.

First off, here's the code:

**index.html**

```
<form id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col-md-4">
 <label class="file">
 <input type="file" id="file1" name="document" multiple>
 <span class="file-custom">Documents</span>
 <button type="button" onclick="enterdata()">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
 
<script>
function enterdata(){
 if ($"data")[0].checkValidity(){
  alert('validity success');
  var token = ''{{ csrf_token }};
  alert('csrf generated');
  $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'/user',
     data: {
      doc1:$('file1').val()
   },
   header: {'X-CSRFToken': token},
   success: function(){
     alert("Added");
     $('#data').trigger("reset");
   }
  })
}else{
  $('data')[0].reportValidity()
  }
}
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def testing_data(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
 doc11 = request.POST['doc1']
 
 request_file = request.FILES['document'] if 'document' in request.FILES else None
        if request_file:
            # save attatched file
            # create a new instance of FileSystemStorage
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            file = fs.save(request_file.name, request_file)
            # the fileurl variable now contains the url to the file. This can be used to serve the file when needed.
            fileurl = fs.url(file)
 landform.objects.create
 (
   mutdoc=doc11,
 )
return HttpResponse('')
```

**models.py**

```
class landform(models.Model):
 mutdoc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('user', testing_data),
 ]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

So, the current code is taking the path and putting it in the mutdoc field in my model, this is alright and I have a lot of other fields that I have omitted from the above code. But apart from all that, the code that gets the file and saves it in the media directory is working fine when I run it independently in another project (without Ajax). But in my project when I combine it in that view above and Ajax, everything else works as expected apart from Django creating a media folder and putting the selected file inside it.

Crawled through tons of other SO threads and blog posts and videos but still can't get it to work.

***Original***

**html**

```
<form method = 'POST' class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{new_form.as_p}}

    <!--Below is our main file upload input -->
        <input type = "file" name = 'document'>
        <p><button type = "submit" class = "waves-effect waves-light btn">Publish</button></p>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def loadpage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # if the post request has a file under the input name 'document', then save the file.
        request_file = request.FILES['document'] if 'document' in request.FILES else None
        if request_file:
            # save attatched file

            # create a new instance of FileSystemStorage
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            file = fs.save(request_file.name, request_file)
            # the fileurl variable now contains the url to the file. This can be used to serve the file when needed.
            fileurl = fs.url(file)

    return render(request, "template.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', loadpage)
]
# only in development
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Did Ajax give you any error message?

Comment: @ha-neul Nope. Ajax is working fine and all 30 fields are being inserted in the DB successfully.
Here's the log from PyCharm :

[01/Dec/2020 19:53:14] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 17941
[01/Dec/2020 19:54:12] "POST /user HTTP/1.1" 200 0

Comment: hi why aren't you use a fileform? looks like the file does not have a model linked to it How are you going to refer that file in the template later? Does your non-ajax way have the model and form associated with the file?

Comment: @ha-neul sorry, I'm unaware of that method. I'm using Django's FileSystemStorage in the above two examples (I've updated the post with the original project in which it's working, you can check that) but the issue is that if everything else is fine, why would it work on one but not the other? As for fileform, I'll take a look at it and see if I'm able to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** replace:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('user', testing_data),
 ]
```

with

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('user/', views.testing_data, name='testing_data'),
]
```

**2.** This cuold be the problem. Try this:

replace:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="document" multiple>
```

with:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="document" >
```

I could not find a doc about if having `multiple`inside of `<input>` will force you to use `request.FILES.getlist('document')`
rather than
`request.FILES['document']` or not, but it is worth to try.

Comment: That's my bad, I wrote that code in the post above and forgot to add the #. It's actually there in the project. This just saves the path in the DB like this: "C:\fakepath\filename.ext". It actually saves it as "fakepath" instead of the actual path.